# Swift: Best way to handle unique/variable cell spacing in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewlayout

Here is an image of iMessage. You can see the red circles show a larger gap between messages than the orange circles.

[image]

Say each cell is one of the chat bubbles: What is the best way to achieve this variable cell spacing in `UIKit`?

I have two thoughts:

1. Find a way using `UICompositionalLayout` to achieve variable item spacing..?
2. Register a unique cell that has extra padding with my `UICollectionView`, and `deque` it when I want that extra padding?

Does anyone have advice on best practices for achieving variable cell spacing for a `UICollectionViewLayout` ?

Thank you!

Comment: u can use different ui for sender and receiver cell and add more spacing for sender at top

Comment: You can use different sections for "from user" and "to user", this way you can manage the space per item, and space per section.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments! Would having say, 100 unique sections still be good practice? The section approach seems more tightly coupled rather than relying on a unique cell with special padding? What is everyone's thoughts? I am leaning towards the different sections approach?

Answer (score 1):

Update: Thanks to @Larme for the comment, I achieved this beautifully and easily:

```swift
func getLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    let size = NSCollectionLayoutSize.init(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(50))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem.init(layoutSize: size)
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: size, subitems: [item])
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection.init(group: group)
    section.interGroupSpacing = 2.0 // group spacing
    let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
    config.interSectionSpacing = 16 // section spacing
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.init(section: section, configuration: config)
}
```

Then, it's as simple as having a function that decides when to append to the previous section vs. initializing a new section. Here's an example of mine:

```swift
func addMessages(_ messages:[Message]) {
    var snap = self.data.snapshot()
    
    for i in messages {
        // If prev and current message has same origin, use prev section
        if snap.sectionIdentifiers.last?.origin == i.origin {
            snap.appendItems([i], toSection: snap.sectionIdentifiers.last!)
        // Else create a new section
        } else {
            snap.appendSections([Section(origin: i.origin)])
            snap.appendItems([i], toSection: snap.sectionIdentifiers.last!)
        }
    }
                    
    self.data.apply(snap)
}
```